# Can you use subdomains of microsoft domain to host your own html websites?

Tags: microsoft-office-365

Like github.io, heroku, they allow you to host content in their subdomain like xxx.github.io, yyyy.heroku.com.

I am wondering can is it possible for me as a global admin of office 365 to host html website at subdomain of Microsoft assets like

*.microsoftonline.com *.office365.com *.microsoft.com ?

So for example, I can host my application on xxx.microsoftonline.com.

Is it possible for you to set cname or A record of xxx.microsoftonline.com to your own domain or ip address?

Or you can edit html file in such subdomain?

Do Microsoft provide such functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot.
But if you have an (free) Azure Subscription you can host a website on `yourapplication.azurewebsites.net`.

It's very easy to set up. You can event edit the webpage directly from the Azure Portal (by running Visual Studio Code directly in the browser)

[**Here you can find a complete step-by-step guide how you can set it up!**](https://docs.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-html) The tutorial [how to setup the azure subscription](https://azure.microsoft.com/pl-pl/free/?ref=microsoft.com&utm_source=microsoft.com&utm_medium=docs&utm_campaign=visualstudio) is also there on the start of the article

If you need something bigger - theres [Azure AppService pricing tiers comparison](https://azure.microsoft.com/pl-pl/pricing/details/app-service/windows/)

Comment: Thanks very much for your kind reply!